# Is there a deeper significance of Professor Denovo's name?

Tags: name-significance, craft-sequence, max-gladstone

The first book in Max Gladstone's Craft Sequence is *Three Parts Dead*. Professor Alexander Denovo, the main antagonist, seeks to gather enough power for himself to become like the gods. (Gods exist in this setting as, essentially, incredibly strong magic users powered by belief and worship.) The most obvious significance of his name is that he is trying to become a *new* god, and his name is pronounced/spelled like the Latin *de novo*. Is there a significance beyond this obvious surface-level new-god-ness?

Comment: might wanna mention that his first name is Alexander. Alexander de novo ... like television, that's half Greek, half Latin, and entirely suggestive.